# Refactoring C function to find diameter of Binary Tree in O(n) to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c, binary-tree

I'm having trouble understanding/re-writing the "optimized" C function given [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/) for find the diameter of a binary tree. I dont understand how its keeping track of the height. I get that its using the second parameter height to accomplish this, but in the code I dont even see the height parameter being used. I have trouble understanding functions in C, I primarily write in JavaScript. I was able to re-write all of the other functions on the page though without issue.

```
/*The second parameter is to store the height of tree.
   Initially, we need to pass a pointer to a location with value
   as 0. So, function should be used as follows:

   int height = 0;
   struct node *root = SomeFunctionToMakeTree();
   int diameter = diameterOpt(root, &height); */
int diameterOpt(struct node *root, int* height)
{
  /* lh --> Height of left subtree
      rh --> Height of right subtree */
  int lh = 0, rh = 0;

  /* ldiameter  --> diameter of left subtree
      rdiameter  --> Diameter of right subtree */
  int ldiameter = 0, rdiameter = 0;

  if(root == NULL)
  {
    *height = 0;
     return 0; /* diameter is also 0 */
  }

  /* Get the heights of left and right subtrees in lh and rh
    And store the returned values in ldiameter and ldiameter */
  ldiameter = diameterOpt(root->left, &lh);
  rdiameter = diameterOpt(root->right, &rh);

  /* Height of current node is max of heights of left and
     right subtrees plus 1*/
  *height = max(lh, rh) + 1;

  return max(lh + rh + 1, max(ldiameter, rdiameter));
}
```

Comment: In JavaScript the closest "equivalent" would be: `function diameterOpts(.., height /* an object */) .. var lh = {value: 0} .. height.value = max(lh.value, rh.value) + 1`. In this case the height variable (supplied from the outside) is used to return the height to the caller via mutation to the object (directly in JavaScript, or via pointer indirection in C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approximate equivalent of passing by reference (as well-commented in sample you've provided) would be object with property:

```
var heightHolder = { height:0};
var diam = diameterOpt(root, heightHolder);
console.log(heightHolder.height);

function diameterOpt(root, heightHolder){
   if (!root)  {
      heightHolder.height = 0; 
      return 0;
   }
   var refLh = {height:0};
   var refRh = {height:0};
   var ldiameter = diameterOpt(root.left, refLh); 
   ....
   heightHolder.height = Math.max(refLh.height, refRh.height) + 1;
   return ...
}
```

---

Normally you would not go such insane route as JavaScript support returning multiple values in more natural way:

```
 function diameterOpt(root){
    if (!root){
       return {height:0, diameter:0};
    }
    var leftResult = diameterOpt(root.left);
    var rightResult = diameterOpt(root.right);

    return {
       height:  Math.max(leftResult.height,rightResult.height) + 1;
       diameter: 
           Math.max(leftResult.height+rightResult.height + 1,
                    Math.max(leftResult.diameter, rightResult.diameter))
       }  
}
```

Comment: Im having a lot of trouble understanding this code. Can you complete the `...` parts.

Comment: @DanielKobe non-compiled/non-tested copy-paste ready code added.

Comment: Awesome. So wait theres no way to do this by using a height parameter, just curious?

Comment: @DanielKobe JavaScript does not have. concept of reference to variable, so - no. On other hand if you have particular syntax in mind there is reasonable chance that it can be achieved with some additional effort.